# Wijgrid destroying data- attributes

Tags: jquery-ui, wijmo

I have some data- attributes that I put into a table row tag.
When I set the table to be a wijgrid the data- attributes are destroyed.

How do I keep wijmo from destroying these attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying attributes on rows (`tr`), they are simply ignored by the plugin (as you experienced), whatever they are (style, class, data...).

It seems voluntary because **the piece of code that would normally extract the attributes for the rows is commented in the plugin source**.

In the method `readTableSection`, we have (i removed the not relevant lines of code in here):

```
readTableSection: function(table, section, readAttributes) {

    ...

    if (table && (section = this.getTableSection(table, section))) {

        for (ri = 0, rowLen = section.rows.length; ri < rowLen; ri++) {

            row = section.rows[ri];
            tmp = [];

            if (readAttributes) {

                // here normally the html attributes of the rows (<tr>) should be extracted
                // but the code is commented !
                tmp.rowAttributes = null; // $.wijmo.wijgrid.getAttributes(row);
                tmp.cellsAttributes = [];

            }

            // here is extracted the html attributes for the cells (<td>)
            for (ci = 0, celLen = row.cells.length; ci < celLen; ci++) {
                tmp[ci] = row.cells[ci].innerHTML;
                if (readAttributes) {
                    tmp.cellsAttributes[ci] = $.wijmo.wijgrid.getAttributes(row.cells[ci], prevent);
                }
            }

            result[ri] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have made a test with "data-" attributes on `td` elements and they are not destroyed.

Note: you have to use the option `readAttributesFromData`.

You may contact the company who develops this plugin to ask why they have commented out this line.

Comment: Now that is completely unexpected. I knew they removed the attributes when they made the wijmo-fied grid. But was hoping there was some option to prevent that. I did not expect that it may be a bug or dead code that caused it.